Injective Infinite Matrix
$\textbf{Background.}$ Let $\{a_i\}_{i\in \Bbb{N}}\subseteq \Bbb{R}_{>0}$. Further assume that $a_i\ne a_j$ for $i\ne j$. Consider the infinite matrix
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots \\
a_1 & \frac{a_2}{2} & a_3 & \ldots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that acts on $\Bbb{R}^{|\Bbb{N}|}$ (The vector space with vectors that have a countable infinite number of real-valued entries).
$\textbf{Claim.}$ $A$ has trivial kernel (or $A$ is injective on $\Bbb{R}^{|\Bbb{N}|}$)
$\textbf{Ideas.}$ Unforunately, just having linearly independent columns/rows is not sufficient for injectivity with an infinite matrix. For example,
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$
has linearly independent columns. Now consider $\vec x = (1,-1,1,-1,\ldots)^T$. Then $B\vec x = \vec 0$. In other words, $B$ is not injective. However, the aforementioned example does not directly relate to my specific problem as my entries are all positive and unique. Any advice or counterexample would be appreciated.
$\textbf{Follow-up.}$ Can I just do normal row operations when considering infinite matrices (Or an infinite homogeneous system of equations)? If so, then it seems that the $A$ matrix I constructed is row equivalent to the identity.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots \\
a_1 & \frac{a_2}{2} & a_3 & \ldots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots \\
0 & -\frac{a_2}{2} & 0 & \ldots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \ldots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & a_3 & \ldots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
a_1 & a_2 & \frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & a_3 & \ldots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & -\frac{a_3}{2} & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
a_1 & 0 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \ldots \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \ldots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Continue this row reduction ad infinitum. It doesn't seem unreasonable to say that $A$ is row equivalent to the identity matrix. That would then imply that $A$ is injective, correct?

I think your follow-up idea is correct. In more detail, if $(x_n)$ was in the kernel of your matrix, then $\sum_n x_n a_in = 0$ for every $i$ (here $A = (a_{ij})$). Thus, $\sum_n x_n (a_{in} - a_{jn}) = 0$ too. Note however, that the crux of this reduction is that $(x_n)$ is assumed to be in the kernel, or, the system is homogeneous.

For a finite sequence of operations, this is OK. But you can do a similar thing with $B$, moving the $1$'s (or $-1$'s when they occur) column by column to the right using appropriate row reductions. The elementwise limit of the process will be well-defined and equal to the identity. See also https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09779

Regarding the matrix $B$, I do not see the row reductions you mention. $B$ is an upper triangular matrix so we would need to clear above, but that's not possible without further affecting the row.
